# How to perfectly forward a struct member?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding, pointer-to-member

I am trying to do some generic programming, in which I take an instance of some struct (which has been registered in some way) and performs a special operation with each of some subset of its members.

I have a trait that looks sort of like this:

```
template <typename S>
struct visitable<S, std::enable_if_t<is_visitable<S>::value>> {
  template <typename V, typename T>
  static void apply_visitor(V && v, T && t) {
    v(t.*(get_registered_member_ptr<S>::value));
  }
}

template <typename V, typename S>
void apply_visitor(V && v, S && s) {
  visitable<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<S>>>::apply_visitor(std::forward<V>(v), std::forward<S>(s));
}
```

This is a simplification, actually there are going to be several member pointers and the visitor will be applied several times. But it gets to the heart of the issue.

In this code `T` is going to be the same type as `S` but with some CV / reference qualifiers, which I'm using so I don't have to type out all the overloads manually. I would like to invoke the visitor with the same value type as the expression that was passed by the user.

But when I want to apply the pointer to member, I have an issue because I can't use `std::forward` anymore to get the right qualifiers when I pass it to the visitor.

Is there a fancy version of `std::forward` that can do that, like, apply the CV and reference qualifiers of first template parameter to the second parameter and give me the result? Or should I just make one up? Or is there a better idiom for this.

Comment: I would not expect well written and designed C++ code to use `remove_cv_t` to such an extreme extent. This looks like a design problem of some kind.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: It's only because, when the type is registered, it has no CV or ref qualifiers, but when it is passed via perfect forwarding, it does. If I don't have `remove_cv_t` and such then either the template specialization isn't found or you need to register it 5 or 6 extra times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::forward<V>(v)(std::forward<T>(t).*(get_registered_member_ptr<S>::value))
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Ahhh... I see, so the `.*` operator will do the right thing with rvalue-references. I didn't realize that. Thanks.

Comment: @chris I know `.` will do the right thing.  I did not double check that `.*` would, but I presume competence of standard writers.