# How to perfectly forward multiple struct members

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, c++14

I'm looking to get some clarity on the correct way to forward *multiple* members from the *same* forwarding reference to a struct.

## Example

Here's an example of forwarding two fields (`one_field` and `another_field`) to a class constructor (`widget`) from a forwarding reference argument `info`. This is how I previously thought we should do it:

```
template<typename Bundle>
auto make_widget(Bundle&& info) {
    return widget(
        std::forward<Bundle>(info).one_field,
        std::forward<Bundle>(info).another_field);
}
```

However, based on a [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/q4mchr/overview_of_different_ways_of_passing_struct/) on reddit's C++ thread, I am worried that this is not the best practice, or worse that this is not safe. According to this thread, it's obviously OK to use this idiom to forward *individual* member fields, but this statement makes me worried it's not safe to forward multiple fields by calling `forward` for than once.

> FWD(t).field: forward t.field, and **invalidates** t and all its members
> (My emphasis)

What concerns me is that my example therefore is incorrect if *all* of the fields of `info` are invalidated by the initial `std::forward<Bundle>(info)`!

How should we be passing on multiple struct fields in a way which is theoretically and practically safe? I'm very much hoping it's not required to write a variant of `std::forward` which moves its argument depending on the semantics of the parent struct type.

## References

Reddit discussion on single field members: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/q4mchr/overview_of_different_ways_of_passing_struct/

Comment on multiple forwards: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/q4mchr/comment/hfzsidd/
*Found this post suggesting this is OK "in practice" but given the subtlety of C++ bugs, I'm keen to know this is OK "in theory" as well! I'm hoping that since under the hood `std::forward` is a `static_cast` to an rvalue type the invalidation doesn't happen to the other fields as would happen if a move constructor was actually called.*

Similar SO question (for a *single* member field): [How to perfectly forward a struct member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023861/how-to-perfectly-forward-a-struct-member)

Thanks all.

Comment: I expect that the same trick to perfectly forward a member field of a struct with a single member field would work for perfectly forwarding each member field of a struct with multiple member fields.

Comment: Your understanding is correct and your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @MarcGlisse, this is reassuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the forward you have already does the correct thing (i.e. forward the member as Bundle) and access a field is not like to invalidate the parent object.

```cpp
template<typename Bundle>
auto make_widget(Bundle&& info) {
    return widget(
        std::forward<Bundle>(info).one_field,
        std::forward<Bundle>(info).another_field
    );
}
```

---

if you want, you can also use something like [`std::forward_like`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward_like) in c++23

```
template<typename Bundle>
auto make_widget(Bundle&& info) {
    return widget(
       std::forward_like<Bundle>(info.one_field),
       std::forward_like<Bundle>(info.another_field)
    );
}
```

Comment: actually I believe there is no way to make member access through dot operator invalidate parent object.

Comment: Gorgeous to have a C++23 option @apple apple thanks for the insight- I'm gonna let the comments above settle and then document the answer based on that.